# batch processing files through an interactive script

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have a functioning interactive script running on `Mac` that sorts and processes files located in an unsorted folder on my desktop.

As it currently stands, the user types `jpg` into the command line, the script executes and iterates through the unsorted folder where it takes these files types and makes a new directory on the desktop and moves them.

Its working terrific, but I want to develop the script further so that I can batch process without having to type single terminal commands one at a time.

i.e. I can type a series of arguments into the terminal `jpg` `gif` `docx`and the script will run and make new desktop directories for `jpg` `gif` `docx`and move all of these file types into such.

The only caveat is, The remaining miscellaneous files in the unsorted folder (.wav png and a whole litany of other extensions) need to have a `miscellaneous` folder created in the desktop and moved into such as soon as I run the batch.

What is the leanest way of achieving such.

```
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" extension
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop; then
    destination="folder$extension"
    # ensure the destination folder exists
    mkdir -p "$destination"
    if mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"; then
        echo "Good News, Your files have been successfully processed"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
read -a extensions -p "give me extensions seperated by spaces:  " # read extensions and put them in array $extensions
for ext in ${extensions[@]}; do  #for each extension stored in the array extensions
echo -e "- Working with extension $ext"
destination="/Users/christopherdorman/desktop/folder$ext"
mkdir -p "$destination"
mv  -v unsorted/*.$ext "$destination"
done

miscellaneous="/Users/christopherdorman/desktop/miscellaneous"    
mv  -v unsorted/*.* "$miscellaneous"; 
# since previously you moved the required extensions to particular desktop folders
# move what ever is left under unsorted folder to the desktop miscellaneous folder
```

Comment: this does not run properly. the folders are created but there is no files moved into them

Comment: The move command it is not tested. I just copied your move command. If it is not working it was not working by the beginning. Try to finetune  the move part. I will try to test it later.

Comment: In my code if you change the move command like this should work:    mv  -v unsorted/*.$ext "$destination" (remove quotes from $ext)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Good Morning, Please enter your file type name for sorting [ENTER]:" all_extensions
if cd /Users/christopherdorman/desktop
  then  while read extension
      do    destination="folder$extension"
        mkdir -p "$destination"
        mv  -v unsorted/*."$extension" "$destination"
      done   <<< "${all_extensions// /$'\n'}"
        mkdir -p foldermisc 
        if mv  -v unsorted/* "foldermisc"
      then  echo "Good News, the rest of Your files have been successfully processed"
        fi
fi
```